# Bugzilla email_in.pl without requiring user accounts

Tags: email, bugzilla

I want to use bugzilla as issue tracking support tool. Users should communicate only using E-Mail, while developers work with bugzilla.

So the first step is creating new bugs for mails, but that fails with the following error:

> There is no user named 'test@test.com'. Either you mis-typed the name or that user has not yet registered for a Bugzilla account.

Is it possible to work around that?

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to change the "from" email in the message to some common account that you set up to specifically handle bugs submitted via email.

You would need to do this before you called email_in.pl http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/api/email_in.html

Comment: Comments should get out to the original reporter. Maybe adding as cc could do that?

Comment: You'd have to set up each user in Bugzilla in order to be able to add them to the CC list. You could add their email to a custom field and then have some other process send the emails.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using LDAP authentication and your directory contains all of your intended users, you could use the syncLDAP.pl script in bugzilla/contrib to create bugzilla users for everyone in the directory.

There are a few gotchas I'll mention in case it helps anyone else..

- You'll need to install the [Net::LDAP](http://ldap.perl.org/) perl module. I used cpan.
- Be sure your BZ_ROOT_DIR is set properly in /contrib/Buzgilla.pm
- If you have multiple LDAP servers configured in parameters, the script will choke. I temporarily removed all but one of the servers.
- I found that entries with no mail attribute defined also caused the script to choke, so I made the following change:

  `my @login_name = @{ $value->{Bugzilla->params->{"LDAPmailattribute"}} };`

  to

  `my @login_name = @{ $value->{Bugzilla->params->{"LDAPmailattribute"}} } if defined $value->{Bugzilla->params->{"LDAPmailattribute"}};`

Run the script with no arguments to see the various usages (eg. readonly, to test without committing changes). Also, as this is a one time sync, you'd need to set up a scheduled task to run it on a suitable interval.

I apologize that this doesn't entirely remove the requirement for user accounts, but at the very least it's a viable solution for anyone that needs LDAP/AD users to be able to email bugzilla to create tickets without manually creating bugzilla accounts.